# The tidySEM package for R is not loading correctly

Tags: r, installation, package

I installed the tidySEM package for R and evertime I load the library, I receive the following error message:

> library(tidySEM)
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidySEM’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
> es gibt kein Paket namens ‘igraph’
> In addition: Warning message:
> Paket ‘tidySEM’ wurde unter R Version 4.0.5 erstellt

Also, when I try to plot with graph_sem, I receive the following error message:

> graph_sem(model = sem_fit, layout = sem_layout)
> Error in graph_sem(model = sem_fit, layout = sem_layout) :
> could not find function "graph_sem"

Does anyone know how to solve the problem? Thanks in advance!
Julia

I tried to reinstall the tidySEM package but it didn't change anything.

Comment: How in the world did you manage to get both English and German messages?  What "locale" have you set for your R installation?

Comment: In any case, you need to provide your OS, the version of R you have installed, whether you are using command-line or gui or RStudio, how you installed `tidySEM` package.